# Change font sizes with style sheets for RStudio presentation

Tags: css, r, markdown, rstudio, presentation

I am using RStudio Presentation and I'd like to change the font size for the main elements (e.g.: header, bullet, and sub bullet).  I was able to add a style sheet to my rmd file but I do not know what to change in the css file.  I have tried changing the font size in various places in the css file but nothing worked.

```
## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
    + Sub bullet
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3
```

Comment: For the header 
`# This is an H1,
## This is an H2
###### This is an H6`

Answer (score 6):

The default style sheet for rstudio presentations is [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/44b1b2815b76013d5a2ba6e9a203ab52be7e5d9e/src/cpp/session/resources/presentation/slides.css)

You can of course have a style sheet, but you can also change the settings on the fly like below.

```
Untitled
========================================================

Slide title
========================================================

<style>

/* slide titles */
.reveal h3 { 
  font-size: 100px;
  color: blue;
}

/* heading for slides with two hashes ## */
.reveal .slides section .slideContent h2 {
   font-size: 40px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: green;
}

/* ordered and unordered list styles */
.reveal ul, 
.reveal ol {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: red;
    list-style-type: square;
}

</style>

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
    + Sub bullet
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3
```

Gives me this

[image]

The `#`, `##`, `###`, etc correspond to `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, etc. Apparently the `h3` goes with the slide titles. It is also important to put the `.reveal` in front of each item if you are changing the rstudio stylesheet.

Comment: So does R supports Css code for generating slides that are more attractive and customized.

Comment: [yes](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532307-Customizing-Fonts-and-Appearance). there is also [ioslides](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html) and [slidify](http://slidify.org) which are popular. you can specify a path to a css file in each